# NGX-Datatables. How to get current table instance?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have component with table, that receive RowData from another component by @Input. How can i get instance of current table.

That's part of my html

```
<ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="inputData"
        [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

And component ts

```
export class GridComponent implements OnChanges {
 @Input() inputData: [object];

 columns1 = [
  { prop: 'name' },
  { name: 'Gender' },
  { name: 'Company' }
 ];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by get instance of current table?

Comment: Also is `[object]` actually a valid type? I think you want here to create a class for input data, so that you get type inference in your code

Comment: I mean some object that contains all data of current table. I've tried to use something like @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;  But if we have 2 or more tables on one page 'table' contains only first table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Viewchild` is the correct method, but you should be using it another way.

Here is what you want to do.

Html:

```
<ngx-datatable
        #firstTable  
        class="material"
        [rows]="inputData"
        [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>

<ngx-datatable
        #secondTable  
        class="material"
        [rows]="inputData"
        [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

Component.ts:

```
export class GridComponent implements OnChanges {
 @Input() inputData: [object]; // This line doesn't look right

 @ViewChild('firstTable') myTable1: DatatableComponent;
 @ViewChild('secondTable') myTable2: DatatableComponent;

 columns1 = [
  { prop: 'name' },
  { name: 'Gender' },
  { name: 'Company' }
 ];
}
```

You can take a look at this page for reference:
http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

**Addition:**

You can also use `@ViewChildren` that selects all of the elements, depending on your needs, docs here:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: Thank's you a lot!

Comment: @Иван consider accepting the answer if this helped you.