# Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-datatable

I followed this [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-data-tables-with-ultimate-features-in-few-steps/) but wherever I add NgxDatatableModule, I just getting this.

Below is the criterias I already have tried.

Added into `app.module.ts` not work

then added to `shared.module` not worked

then `page.module`   not worked

All time just getting

> `Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'.`

and interesting part is when before `ngx-datatable` , I installed `ngx-bootstrap` then same error occuring with ngx-bootstrap properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might template reference variable needed so Try defining instance of datatable with

```
@ViewChild('firstTable') myTable: DatatableComponent;
```

referred from [NGX-Datatables. How to get current table instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072556/ngx-datatables-how-to-get-current-table-instance)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import "NgxDatatableModule" in your app-module and add it in the imports.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [NgxDatatableModule],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```